# What is "curPopup" and why have I received a notification about it?

Tags: windows-10, virus, notification-area, virus-removal

This notification just appeared, what does it mean and is it a virus?
[image: curPopup notification screenshot]

Windows 10 professional PC.

Comment: Looks like a website notification that is nonfunctional due to browser configuration.

Comment: That sounds plausible, as I think the internet had been lost just before that. (I18n looks like a translation function) Thanks!